# How to pass a selected image from ImagePickerController to second view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uiimagepickercontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I've tried exhaustively to find the answer to this problem.  In the app that I am creating the user will click addImage button and then select an image from the photo library (or camera) from ImagePickerController and then that selected image gets passed to an image view on a second view controller.

I know how to do this when the image view is on the same view as the addImage button but can't figure out how to properly use a segue to pass the image to the second view.  Hopefully, someone can help me sort this out.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

        var newImage = UIImage(named: "")


    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imagePicker.delegate = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func addImage(sender: UIButton) {

        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please Get An Image", message: "Choose from below", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .Default, handler: {(action) -> Void in

                        self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
                        self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .Default, handler: {(action) -> Void in

                        self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
                        self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: {(action) -> Void in

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)



        }))


            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

        newImage = image

     //not sure about this next line here...
     performSegueWithIdentifier("VC2", sender: self)


      self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        var secondViewController: VC2 = segue.destinationViewController as! VC2
        secondViewController.imageView.image = newImage




    }


}// end of app
```

Comment: Are you sure the UIImageView on the VC2 is already instantiated when you try to set newImage to it?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Can you explain how I would do that?  I have created an IBOutlet for the image view on VC2.  Is there another step that I need to do?  in the View Did Load I set the imageView.Image = holderImage which is suppose to hold the image selected in the first View.

Comment: As this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31996503/2362508) suggested, you can set a breakpoint on prepareForSegue function and check if your view controller is instantiated properly

Answer (score 0):

OK susan, so when you click "Use Photo" in the preview part of the camera, that's where you want to implement to segue to the second VC.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

    newImage = image

          dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
            //Will call segue name
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Your_Segue_name", sender: self)
        })
}
```

EDIT: The above code will segue after you've confirmed that you want to use the image.

In your second VC, have a holder to hold then sent that holder image to your UIImageView. In your 1st VC, sent the image to transfer to the holder image.

Your SecondVC:

```
@IBOutlet var imgView: UIImageView!
var holderImage: UIImage?
```

In your viewDidLoad()

```
imgView.image = holderImage.image
```

Comment: I have changed my code but after I select a photo library image from the imagePicker , it just goes right back to the first view controlelr.  it does not segue to the second.   I created the segue from the addImage button.  should I be creating the segue from another point?

Answer (score 0):

you should not pass the `UIImage` by using the `UIImageView` object because this is not a Good idea to pass the image like this, Instead you can create UIImage object in SecondViewController simple pass the `UIImage` object to that and in **SecondVC**  use this image object like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if imageView != nil {
            imageView.image = newImage
        }
 }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.  I have changed the code but I seem to have trouble in the segue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the segue has its identifier set as "VC2". Also, instead of setting

```
secondViewController.imageView.image = newImage
```

expose a property on your secondViewController that takes the image. Set the property with the image in prepareForSegue.

```
secondViewController.image = newImage
```

Then, in viewDidLoad on secondViewController set its imageView with the value from the property.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  imageView.image = image
}
```

In your code the ImageView on the second controller doesn't exist yet because of the view life cycle.

You can also set a breakpoint in prepareForSegue to make sure it's being called properly and the second controller is being set properly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I have changed by code but after I select a photo library image using the imagePicker, it just goes right back to first view controller and does not seque to second vc.  I have the correct segue ID.  I think the error is in where I am making the segue.  I currently have the segue going from the addImage button to the second vc.  Is this wrong?  Because this button is also used to trigger the alert view to select a photo.

Comment: @SusanStarkman yes, I believe you're on the right path. If the button action shows the alert view and it's hooked up to the segue the segue will fire after the alert view is shown. One way around this is to create the segue from the first view itself to the second view, instead of the button. You can create the segue this way: In your storyboard, at the top of the first view there is a yellow circle - ctrl-drag from there to the second view and make sure to give the segue the proper identifier. Then you should implement the completion handler as whereisleo provided.

Comment: Thank you Davey.  I think that may solve the problem.  Thanks for taking the time to explain that to me.